# using primitive type as Generic object

Tags: java, arrays, generics, primitive-types

I have a method for retrieving elements from an array and I would like to use the same method for several primitive types (int[],double[],...). The method is as follows:

```java
public static int[] getElementsFromTo(int[] data,int from, int to){
    int[] selectedData = new int[to-from];
    for (int idx = from; idx < to; idx++){
        selectedData[idx-from]=data[idx];
    }
    return selectedData;
}
```

I've seen some posts with similar question but I couldn't find a good answer, or at least understand it. The closest response is in this thread [Java Generic Primitive type n-d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767168/java-generic-primitive-type-n-d-array).

Some suggested using Object[] and then at runtime get the primitive type, but I don't know how. I guess the method's signature would look something similar to :

```java
public static Object[] getElementsFromTo(Object[] data,int from, int to)
```

But how can I get the *data*'s type to instantiate *selectedElements* array with the proper primitive type?

Lots of thanks

Comment: There's no solution to your problem. Every primitive array is a distinct type with no common abstraction. `Object[]` in **not** a supertype of any primitive array type.

Comment: So the only solution is overiding the method, copypasting the same code but initializing the returned array with proper primary type?

Answer (score 5):

The closest you can achieve is using the following

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <A> A copyOf(A array, int from, int to) {
    int len = to - from;
    A a = (A) Array.newInstance(array.getClass().getComponentType(), len);
    System.arraycopy(array, from, a, 0, len);
    return a;
}
```

This will copy array of primitive and non primtive array types, but use reflections to do it.

Comment: It's...usually a code smell, and frequently fragile.  This code, for example, will break badly if you try passing a non-array type.  But it's the closest you can get.

Comment: There is no way to let the compiler know that `A` must be an array. Its a weakness of System.arraycopy as well. Some IDEs will warn you if you use a non-array type.

Comment: mmm and am I forced to use System.arraycopy? cannot use direct asignation such as:   array[idx] = a[idx]?

Comment: You can use `Array.set(to_array, i, Array.get(from_array, i + from))` but it will be *much* slower as it turns every value into an object (using reflections to do it)

Comment: I personally think people complain way too much about reflection. My first-choice language is Clojure and I live happily with no compile-time type safety. This solution is great.

Comment: humm  so then, it will be better to just enlarge the code overriding the method. Then I wonder if there is any way to share the javadoc from one method with its overrided versions wihout having to copy all the text. By now I'm using a link to the overided method. Is that the proper way?

Comment: You can't override static methods. Where you thinking of overloading? You might want to look at `Arrays.copyOf` to see how that is done.

Comment: BTW, A custom loop for a specific type can be faster than using System.arraycopy.

Comment: ups, yes, I was thinking of overloading. I mean using the same method name with different signature. Just modifying the primitive type of the returned and input variables.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I liked the suggestion of `Arrays` methods, there is a method which does almost what I'm lo0king for `Arrays.copyOfRange`. The only missing feature is to be able to retrieve elements with decreasing index. Is there any method for reversing arrays?

Comment: For that you would need to use a loop. I suggest avoiding reflections for this because it would be very slow.

Comment: ok ok that's the way it is done by now. I'll keep the looping approach and overload the methods for proper primitive types. I've used arrays for improving speed, but I guess that using `ArrayList` instead of arrays would allow to use generics to have only one method and avoid the need for overloading for different primitive types. Am I right using arrays for improving speed instead of using `ArrayList`? or there is no such speed performance difference between these two types?

Comment: There is a high relative difference, but it can be very small compared to whatever the rest of your application is doing.